# transformIgnorePatterns not working correctly in jest config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transformation, babel-jest, ignore

I am getting "Jest encountered an unexpected token" jest failure in two components in node modules.

*\ui\node_modules\ @us-shield\react-breadcrumb\dist\esm\index.js*

*\ui\node_modules\react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack.js*

Tried transformIgnorePatterns in jest config as below:-

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?!(@us-shield|react-pdf)/)",
    "/react-pdf/",
  ],
```

After this, first error gone , but 2nd error related to "react-pdf" remains same.

Anyone please advice. Thanks.